# How to render a weight element?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to render a weight element but it doesn't works I just have as output an empty string. But when I try to render a checkbox I get the correct output.

For the **weight** element:

```
$weight = array(
  '#type' => 'weight', 
  '#title' => t('Weight'), 
  '#default_value' => 1, 
  '#delta' => 10, 
);

// For Drupal 7.    
dpm(drupal_render($weight));
// For Drupal 8.
kint(\Drupal::service('renderer')->render($weight));
```

***Output:*** An empty string.

For the **checkbox** element.

```
$check = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Dry run'),
  '#description' => t('Test run without deleting revisions but seeing the output results.'),
);
// For Drupal 7.
dpm(drupal_render($check));
// For Drupal 8.
kint(\Drupal::service('renderer')->render($check));
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="form-checkbox" />  <label class="option">Dry run </label>

<div class="description">Test run without deleting revisions but seeing the output results.</div>
</div>
```

So, I think that the `drupal_render()` function and renderer service are working fine because the checkbox is rendered, but the weight element not, I'm missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The select element is built in [Weight::processWeight()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Weight.php/function/Weight%3A%3AprocessWeight/8.4.x):

```
  /**
   * Expands a weight element into a select element.
   */
  public static function processWeight(&$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, &$complete_form) {
    $element['#is_weight'] = TRUE;

    $element_info_manager = \Drupal::service('element_info');
    // If the number of options is small enough, use a select field.
    $max_elements = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('weight_select_max');
    if ($element['#delta'] <= $max_elements) {
      $element['#type'] = 'select';
      $weights = [];
      for ($n = (-1 * $element['#delta']); $n <= $element['#delta']; $n++) {
        $weights[$n] = $n;
      }
      $element['#options'] = $weights;
      $element += $element_info_manager->getInfo('select');
    }
    // Otherwise, use a text field.
    else {
      $element['#type'] = 'number';
      // Use a field big enough to fit most weights.
      $element['#size'] = 10;
      $element += $element_info_manager->getInfo('number');
    }

    return $element;
  }
```

Which is only called in form building, not in normal rendering.

Comment: So, there is not possible to render it if you are not rendering a form?

Comment: Do you think that this should be changed in Core? Is weird that ymou can't do it in a normal way.

Comment: No, although there are form elements which can be used in a normal render context, most prominent is `table` (don't know if there are more), in this case it wouldn't make much sense to use it outside of a form.

Comment: Sometimes I need to render elements in a table, this is the problem that I have, take a look at http://cgit.drupalcode.org/node_revision_delete/tree/src/Form/NodeRevisionDeleteAdminSettings.php?h=8.x-1.x#n149 here a dropbutton is rendered in a table row, but when I need to renden a weight element is not possible.

Comment: This is probably not a good idea for any form element, rendering when building a form. The rendered form elements won't get processed (this is why the mentioned process method is not called) and at this time there is no render context to catch the bubbleable metadata, so you loose attachments, caching ...

Comment: Take a year but I found how don't render the element inside the table, this is the commint and was as easy as use the 'data' index to add the element. :-)